# I can't print images with laravel and vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm getting stuck in an ecommerce development project using Laravel and Vue. I can't make the images appear dynamically in the index view of the product. I'm able to upload and print the images in the show view and these are stored in storage / app / images.

The problem is that the image_url attribute of a product is nullable so it may or may not have an image and the idea is to show them when they have one.

Here is the code of the component ProductCardComponete.vue that is where I develop the code itself.

```
<template lang="html">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="card">
            <header class="bg-dark padding">
            </header>

            <div class="justify-content-center">

                    <!-- <img v-for="product in products" v- if="product.extension" :src="'/productos/images/'+product.id+product.extension"> 
-->
                <img :src="'/productos/images/34.jpeg'" class="card-img-top">

        </div>
        <div class="card-body padding">
            <h2 class="card-title">
                <a :href="'/productos/'+product.id">
                    {{product.title}}
                </a>
            </h2>
            <h4 class="card-subtitle">{{product.humanPrice}}</h4>
            <p class="card-text">{{product.description}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props:{
            product: {
                type: Object
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Of course, when I put the route in a static way, it works. But I don't know how I could arrive at the solution to show it dynamically and the way of showing the image if the product has one.

[image: Here is with a static Route]

Finally here is a link to the github Repo of the project just in case.
[Github Repo](https://github.com/Casti22/Paytiti2)

Comment: what is the image src printed in browser when you got issue?

Comment: did you make storage link

Comment: Is `products` defined on the component somewhere (prop/data/computed etc) and is it a valid array of product objects? You can use the [Vue devtools extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en) to inspect the state of your components.

Answer (score 0):

Images should be saved in `storage/app/public/` and you should make a symlink so that you can access `storage` folder in `public` folder. Otherwise you will stuck in accessing images. Read this official [doc.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#the-public-disk)